# anyone with a solution to this error, type=1400 audit: avc: denied { read write }

Tags: android, selinux

My Android  application is saving data on SQLite and working fine on various android versions, but when installed from playstore some users cannot use the application, after debugging I get this error

type=1400 audit: avc: denied { read write }

I have added permissions for  WRITE EXTERNAL STORAGE, READ EXTERNAL STORAGE but has not solved